# UIBarButtonItem is not working

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I change the UIBarButtonItem title at run time but it does not work

```
if(self.toolbarItems!=nil)
    {
        NSArray *toolbaritem=self.toolbarItems;
        UIBarButtonItem* tmpeditButton =[toolbaritem objectAtIndex:0];
        tmpeditButton.title=@"Done";
        NSLog(@"log %@",tmpeditButton.title);
    }
```

Log is always displays the value of NULL. Why and how to fix that?

Comment: I would check to see if self.toolbarItems==nil.

Comment: I got it. I used initWithBarButtonSystemItem. So, I change to initWithTitle and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem  alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
```